# Period in .Net 3.5 Regex.IsMatch

Tags: regex, vb.net

I came across this regular expression in vb.net 3.5 code:

```
Regex.IsMatch(strString, "^[\w\s.+'\-\(\)\/\,\&\#]+$")
```

What is really confusing me is the ".+" part.  I was under the impression that the period means any character and the plus sign means one or more.  Following this, I feel like this regular expression should allow anything!  But it doesn't, so I must be misunderstanding something.  In testing it, it seems like the period and the plus sign are being taken as literals.

Could somebody help explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, it would mean "one or more of any symbol," but the `[ ]` brackets make it a [character set/class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which ignores special characters. So, in that regex, it's literally looking for a `.` or a `+`. My guess is that this regex does not do whatever it was intended to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that all of those characters are enclosed in a *[character-group]*.  The escaping rules are different in character-groups than they are elsewhere in a RegEx expression.  For instance, according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `\b` inside a character-group means a backspace character whereas, outside of a character-group, it is an anchor that matches a word boundary.

According to the [Regular-Expressions.info documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash.

Therefore, in your example RegEx expression, it looks for any one of the characters in that bracketed list, including either the literal `.` or `+` character.  If you think about it, it wouldn't make any sense to use a `.` to mean "any character" inside of a character-group.  Doing so would make the group, itself, moot.  And certainly, using the `+` character to mean "one or more times" inside of a character-group really makes no sense.

Comment: ohhhhh ok that helps so much!  So this regex could be simplified to "^[\w\s.+'-()/,&#]+$" and mean the same thing yeah?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It's certainly easier to read that way.  You'd have to test it to be sure, since the official MSDN documentation for the .NET RegEx implementation seems to be a bit sparse in this regard.

Comment: thanks! also I have to correct my last comment.  I think there needs to be a backlash before the dash because after reading the link you posted, the dash is still a special character inside of the character class.  So i'll end up with this "^[\w\s.+'\-()/,&#]+$" .  I will test it though as you said.  Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

`.+` is mean any symbol in an amount of one or more. Maybe you need to escape dot like `\.+`?

Comment: thanks for the response!  so does that mean this regular expression should allow anything? but when i test it, "$" gets rejected for example

Comment: Yes, it like so. Try to test `$` symbol with `\.+`, please

Comment: Actually, those brackets make it a character class (escape characters aren't recognized)

Answer (score 0):

Within the square parenthesis, dot and plus don't have their special meaning. The square brackets define a "character class". It does not contain a string but a set of characters allowed at this position.

So the expression [\w\s.+'-()/\,\&#] creates a character class of letters, digits, underscore, spaces, dots, pluses, single quotes, minuses, opening round brackets, closing round brackets, slashes, commas, ampersands and hashmarks.

The + behind the square parenthesis means you expect one or more characters of this character class.